# python multiprocessing Customized managers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create a custom multiprocessing manager, following the example:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y):
        return x * y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    maths = manager.Maths()
    print maths.add(4, 3)         # prints 7
    print maths.mul(7, 8)         # prints 56
```

But, when I run `manager.start()` the kernel stuck and nothing happen, I don't know why. I am using spyder IDE, but also pycharm IDE is not working.

Can anyone help why I can't run this code properly.

Comment: Which OS are you running on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Can't replicate the problem under Windows 10 and PyCharm. (Better use it as context manager.)